# I am sending data from client to server in java

Tags: java, sockets

I am new to java and sending some data from client to server using UDP as protocol but i am unable to recieve data at server's side.Basically what i am trying to do is that at clients end i am reading a file into arraylist and sending arraylist's indexes chunk by chunk to server using datagram call . Following is my client:

```
package updclient;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.rmi.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;

public class udpclient {

    public static DatagramSocket clientSocket;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException
    {
        try {
            clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    System.out.println("Enter client hostname:");
    Scanner obj =new Scanner(System.in);
    String Ip=obj.nextLine();

    InetAddress ipaddress=null;
    try{
    ipaddress=InetAddress.getByName(Ip);
    }catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Enter the port");
    int port=Integer.parseInt(obj.nextLine());



    ArrayList<String> filer = new ArrayList<String>(); // arraylist banayi    
    Scanner fileScanner = null;
    try {


        fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("d:\\mahnoor.txt")); //read karay ga
        System.out.println("File read");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (fileScanner.hasNext()){
    //  System.out.println("File read");
       filer.add(fileScanner.next());
    }

    for (String s : filer)
        System.out.println("The content " + s);

    //for(int i=0;i<filer.size();i++){
        String wow = (String) filer.get(0);




    //System.out.println("Enter the message to send to sender");
    //integers a;
    //String a=obj.nextLine();
    byte[] buf=wow.getBytes();

    System.out.println("Sending:");
    DatagramPacket send=new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length,ipaddress,port);

    try {
        clientSocket.send(send);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DatagramPacket rec=new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length);
    try {
        clientSocket.receive(rec);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String message=new String(rec.getData());
    System.out.println(message);
    obj.close();

}
}
```

and at server i am simply waiting for clients message and then printing the message but i think i am getting stuck at 
serverSocket.receive(IN);
This line.

Here's my server's code:

```
package udp_server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class udpserver {

private DatagramSocket serverSocket;
private byte[] buf =new byte[1024];

public udpserver(int ServePort)throws SocketException
{
serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(ServePort);   

}


public void SendingMessage(String Message,DatagramPacket i) throws IOException{
    buf=Message.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket info = null;
    InetAddress IpAddress=info.getAddress();

    int port = info.getPort();
    DatagramPacket Out=new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length,IpAddress,port);
    serverSocket.send(Out);
}


public DatagramPacket RecievingMessage() throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Waiting for message");
    DatagramPacket IN=new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length);
    System.out.println("Waiting for message");
    serverSocket.receive(IN);
    System.out.println("Waiting for message");

    String message = new String(IN.getData());

    System.out.println("The message recieved is:" +message);

    return IN;
}
public void RunServer() throws IOException
{
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true)
    {
        DatagramPacket temp=RecievingMessage();
        String Message=in.nextLine();
                SendingMessage(Message,temp);

    }
}

}
```

And here's main for server:

```
package udp_server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Source{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("THIS IS SERVER");
        System.out.println("Enter the port number for the server");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int port=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());


            udpserver obj = null;
            try {
                obj = new udpserver(port);
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                obj.RunServer();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }





        in.close();
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to fix it , for time being i am only getting one index of arraylist at clients side and sending it to the server. But i am not able to recieve it at servers side.

Comment: Are you using the same port on your client and server? Also are you sure your using the ip address `127.0.0.1` or an address which loops back to your machine to connect to your server?

Comment: im using 11 port no. for both client and server.. is it okay?

Comment: and im entering random ip address as it's giving me error for localhost,should i use 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: I wouldnt use port `11` because it is likely being used by your system in some way. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers . You will probably want to pick a port number which is > 1000 to be sure your not attempting to use a port which is used by another application. 

You should be using the ip address `127.0.0.1` if you are running the server on the same computer as the client. This address is how you reference your own computer. `localhost` is an alias for `127.0.0.1`

Comment: okay recieved thanks alottt